# Ghostscript PDF to JPEG conversion

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

When I try to conver a PDF to JPEG thumbnails I get the following errors:

> [0] => Error: /invalidaccess in --run--
>       [1] => Operand stack:
>       [2] =>    --dict:8/17(L)--   F2   83   --dict:5/5(L)--   --dict:5/5(L)--   SymbolMT   --dict:11/12(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   CIDFontObject   --dict:6/6(L)--   --dict:6/6(L)--   222063
>   --dict:6/6(L)--   --nostringval--   PDFCIDFontName   SymbolMT
>       [3] => Execution stack:
>       [4] =>    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1862   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3
>   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   2   1   16   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
>   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-- 
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
>       [5] => Dictionary stack:
>       [6] =>    --dict:1155/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:106/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:285/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:21/40(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--
>       [7] => Current allocation mode is local
>       [8] => GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
>       [9] => convert: Postscript delegate failed `fullset.pdf': No such file or directory @ pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/611.
>       [10] => convert: missing an image filename`fullset.jpg' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2800.

Anyone have any idea about why this is happening?

It's working fine on my dev server (windows, imagemagik 6.8.6, ghostscript 9.07) but on the live server (linux, imagemagik 6.5.4, ghostscript 8.70) I get those errrors.

I tried to get hosting to update imagemagik and ghostscript but they said they cannot get the new versions to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you are getting a Ghostscript error, and the version which you say works is GS 9.07, and the version you say fails is 8.70. My guess would be you need to update the version of Ghostscript on the server to something rather more recent. I can't see any reason why a new version of Ghostscript wouldn't work on the server, but if nobody ever reports this as a bug we aren't going to fix it, are we ? Maybe your hosting provider should open a bug report.....

Comment: for me im using ghostscript 9.06, after using other versions such as 9.07 or the old ones, it turned that this ver is the most stable one and im using it in both linux and windows

Comment: i had the same issue with GS 9.01, after update to version 9.18, i had better error message from imageMagik/Gs.